# Find values in a matrix and sum when found

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `X(1e4,20)` which takes on values `0:4`.
I'm interested in finding (row by row) the number of times values are ~=0, ==1&2&3 and ==3

Why doesn't 
eg:

```
X=randi([0 4],1e4,20)

for ii=1:1e4
  onestwosorfours(ii,1)=sum(X(ii,:)==1|2|4)
end
```

work?

I've ended up doing

```
sum(X(ii,:)==1)+sum(X(ii,:)==2), etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is wrong:

```
sum( X(ii,:)==1|2|4 )
```

You are finding the **bitwise or**  of `1`,`2` and `4` which is `true`, because anything other than `false` or `0` is `true`. Then you are finding the amount of times that the array equals the number.

Instead, rewrite it as :

```
sum( X(ii,:)==1 |  X(ii,:)==2 |  X(ii,:)==4 )
```

Or, even better

```
numel( X(ii,:)==1 |  X(ii,:)==2 |  X(ii,:)==4 )
```

Which clarifies what you really meant.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have the `A == b` parts each time for the logical or of the results:

```
X=randi([0 4],1e4,20);

for ii=1:1e4
  onestwosorfours(ii,1)=sum( X(ii,:)==1 | X(ii,:) == 2 | X(ii,:) == 4);
end
```